# Cannot create new Android application project width ADT 23.0.2

Tags: android

I'm using Eclipse Indigo to develop Android Application. I have  just upgrated ADT to       version 23.0.2.1259578, SDK Tools to version 23.0.2 and SDK Platform-Tools and SDK Build-Tools to version 20.
Now, when I try to create a New Android Project, no Wizard Window appears and in the log file generated under .metadata folder of my workspace I find the following error lines

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2014-07-18 14:49:13.065
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument not valid
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4263)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4197)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4168)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:468)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo.setItems(Combo.java:1576)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.NewProjectPage.createControl(NewProjectPage.java:281)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard.createPageControls(Wizard.java:174)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createPageControls(WizardDialog.java:736)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createContents(WizardDialog.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1089)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.NewWizardShortcutAction.run(NewWizardShortcutAction.java:122)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: First try Googling for "Unhandled event loop exception". There are several other SO questions about this error. Second, you should get a newer version of Eclipse, preferrably Luna.

Answer (score 0):

You should start by downloading and installing the very latest ADT bundle.  It is designed to install all the proper versions and dependencies, and is a simple download.  I think updating the various pieces, as you have alluded to is challenging.

Bottom line, I would start over and install a fresh installation of the ADT tools.  This won't effect your existing projects, since they live external to the ADT directory.

Download from here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html